# Replace the normal intent with pending

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

There is an activity which is started normally by:

```
intent = new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, LiveStatusActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**LiveStatusActivity** is the newest activity, that is started by CheckOutActivity. 
Now lets say LiveStatusActivity lies on the top of the activity stack.

At the same time, I am starting a pending intent on notification received,

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, LiveStatusActivity.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

On pending intent activity, previous LiveStatusActivity which was started by another activity should be updated/replaced.

Right now, LiveStatusActivity is started(by pending intent) and another same activity is still there on back of it.

ie. LiveStatusActivity(top t `by pending intent`)-----> LiveStatusActivity(t-1 `by checkoutactivity`)---->.....

Tried various flags, checked lot of answer at S.O, all in vain.
I also tried putting `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
  make your LiveStatusActivity as android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest.xml


  and in your LiveStatusActivity override the onNewIntent(Intent intent) method
  So when it will be called second time this onNewIntent() will be called and inisde that you can update your Activity.
```

Remove this flag as well
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);